# Multiprocessing and speed execution

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am trying to learn how to run in parrarel way few functions to speed up my code. Here is my toy program which takes slightly more time than a regular code (without multiprocessing):

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process


def factorial(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

def fibonacci(n):
    """ Returns Fibonacci Number at nth position using recursion"""
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)

p1=Process(target=factorial(40))
p2=Process(target=fibonacci(40))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()

print("We're done")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, "What am I missing?" is too broad and we don't have enough information about what you're trying to achieve (and why). Please clarify and add the information **to the question** (meaning, not as a comment)

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is not the correct way to pass arguments to your function, you should do something like :`Process(target=fibonacci, args=(40,))`. See the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiprocessing adds some overhead:

1. You need to start the process. Once the calculation takes long enough, that is less of an issue, but it does add overhead.
2. You need to serialize (via pickle) the objects sent to the worker subprocess. For small objects this is trivial overhead, for large objects it can add up.
3. There's some benchmark effects from things like hyperthreading and turboboost, where single CPUs might do a little better than you'd think.

In your case, however, the issue (as one of the comments implied but didn't explicitly say) is that the code is actually running in the main process. You're not passing the `fibonacci` function to the worker processes, you're passing the *result* of `fibonacci(40)` to the worker processes.